# Asset pipeline a few css file not found for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

This is my css file, but only admin_layout.css.scss and admin_style.css.scss not found.

I could not upload photo, so I wrote a blog.

my blog: [Rails a few css not found 404](http://julytwilight.com/2013/06/05/Rails-a-few-css-not-found-404.html)

Answer (score 3):

In your `config/application.rb` you need to add the following

```
config.assets.precompile += %w[ admin_layout.css admin_style.css ]
```

You can learn more about this in the **[Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)** Rails Guide. Specifically

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (i.e., .coffee and .scss files are not automatically included as they compile to JS/CSS):
>
> ```
>   [ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
> ```
>
> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:
>
> ```
>   config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
> ```

Comment: Please, accept the Answer if it's solved your problem (the green check under the votes next to my Answer)